# How to terminate another container in the same pod when your main container finish its job

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Using OpenShift 3.9, I run a daily CronJob that consists of 2 containers:

1. A Redis server
2. A Python script that uses the Redis server

When the python script finishes its execution, the container is terminated normally but the Redis server container stays up.

Is there a way to tell the Redis server container to automatically terminate its execution when the python script exit? Is there an equivalent to the depends_on of docker compose?

Comment: Have you tried to send `SHUTDOWN` command to the Redis server? Please take a look here: [Redis.io: Shutdown](https://redis.io/commands/shutdown).

Comment: thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Dawid Kruk comment, I added this line at the end of my python script to shutdown the server:

```
os.system('redis-cli shutdown NOSAVE')
```

It effectively terminates the container.